# How to kill airflow worker properly (with celery executor)?

Tags: airflow

I can start an "airflow worker" (with a celery executor) but I don't know how to kill it properly. I have the impression that many subprocesses are created and I don't know how to shut them gracefully.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't this a superuser question?

Comment: I don't think so : Stack Overflow is for programmers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally set up the Airflow processes as systemd processes and just run systemctl stop airflow-* however I think you can simply kill the main airflow-worker process with a standard linux kill command? Probably what the systemd daemon does anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To stop a worker running on a machine you can use:

```
airflow celery stop
```